# Working on Magento's field

Tags: magento2

I just started learning Magento, need to get more experience working with it.

I have done installed and gone through admin side of Magento.

Adding customers ,Products ,pricing, categories, shipping and installing modules.

According to that.

What is the name of the position to start looking a job doing that with Magento?

Comment: magento trainee, Junior magento developer or internship in magento field.

Comment: Magento Trainee Is a word that suite on your profile.